# CodeIgniter GROUP_CONCAT and join

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to figure a way to join these two tables together, which I was able to do, but if it found more than one value that matched, it showed everything from the product table again. Now I am trying to use the MySQL group_concat together to be able to list all of tName in one field in the array but I keep getting an error with MySQL:

> Error Number: 1064
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM (`sp_product`) LEFT OUTER JOIN `sp_product_type` ON `sp_product_type`.`tCat' at line 2
>
> SELECT `sp_product`.`name`, `sp_product`.`price`, `sp_product`.`perm_name`, `sp_product`.`description`, GROUP_CONCAT(product_type.tName SEPARATOR FROM (`sp_product`) LEFT OUTER JOIN `sp_product_type` ON `sp_product_type`.`tCategory` = `sp_product`.`type` WHERE `perm_name` = 'bacon'

```
$this->db->select('product.name, product.price, product.perm_name, product.description, GROUP_CONCAT(product_type.tName SEPARATOR ',') as product_type.tName'); 
$this->db->from('product');
$this->db->where('perm_name', $this->uri->segment(2));
$this->db->join('product_type', 'product_type.tCategory = product.type', 'LEFT OUTER');
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: We should not see `$this->uri->segment(2)` in a model method.  Submitted data should be received ONLY in the controller, then distributed to other layers as needed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Seems problem with improper quotes.

It should be `GROUP_CONCAT(product_type.tName SEPARATOR ",")`

Try below :

```
$this->db->select('product.name, product.price, product.perm_name, product.description, GROUP_CONCAT(product_type.tName SEPARATOR ",") as product_type.tName'); 
    $this->db->from('product');
    $this->db->where('perm_name', $this->uri->segment(2));
    $this->db->join('product_type', 'product_type.tCategory = product.type', 'LEFT OUTER');
    $query = $this->db->get();
```

Comment: And maybe should pass a `false` parameter to `select` - because of wrong protect algorithm...

Comment: I still get an error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'sp_product`) LEFT OUTER JOIN `sp_product_type` ON `sp_product_type`.`tCategory` ' at line 1

Comment: Once I did this I get only 1 row of data including other row's ids together. How can I get a separate row for each data with separate column?

Comment: We should not see `$this->uri->segment(2)` in a model method.  Submitted data should be received ONLY in the controller, then distributed to other layers as needed.

Answer (score 4):

You should use false as the second parameter in your select to skip escaping:

```
$this->db->select('GROUP_CONCAT(product_type.tName SEPARATOR ",") as product_type.tName', false);
```

Answer (score 1):

user319198 was off to a good start but his answer does not work.  **The working answer is as follows.**

```
$this->db->select('product.name, product.price, product.perm_name, product.description, GROUP_CONCAT(product_type.tName SEPARATOR) as tName'); 
    $this->db->from('product');
    $this->db->where('perm_name', $this->uri->segment(2));
    $this->db->join('product_type', 'product_type.tCategory = product.type', 'LEFT OUTER');
    $query = $this->db->get();
```

Notice I removed `SEPARATOR ","` and renamed the field in (`as product_type.tName'`) to a field name that is not in the database. 
**This has been tested and is working.**

Comment: We should not see `$this->uri->segment(2)` in a model method.  Submitted data should be received ONLY in the controller, then distributed to other layers as needed.

Answer (score 1):

no need to mention separator as comma(,) in group concat, as by default it will take comma(,) only in group concat

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) documentation:

Change this:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(product_type.tName SEPARATOR
```

To this:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(product_type.tName SEPARATOR ', ')
```

You're mixing the `'`

'product.name, product.price, product.perm_name, product.description, GROUP_CONCAT(product_type.tName SEPARATOR ',') as product_type.tName');

Try this:

```
"product.name, product.price, product.perm_name, product.description, GROUP_CONCAT(product_type.tName SEPARATOR ',') as product_type.tName");
```

Answer (score 0):

For #Claremont, #user319198, #FredTheLover, #Mosty Mostacho
Please keep in mind while developing any project using CodeIgniter that to select multiple data or using compound statements in the select query of the Codeigniter you need to define the second parameter of the select query. Like

```
$this->db->select('(SELECT SUM(company.amount) FROM payments WHERE company.invoice_id=4') AS amount_paid', FALSE);
```

Because
`$this->db->select()` accepts an optional second parameter. If you set it to **FALSE**, CodeIgniter will not try to protect your field or table names with backticks. This is useful if you need a compound select statement.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be like this:

```
$this->db->select('product.name, product.price, product.perm_name, product.description')
   ->select(' GROUP_CONCAT(product_type.tName SEPARATOR ",") as product_type.tName', FALSE); 
$this->db->from('product');
$this->db->where('perm_name', $this->uri->segment(2));
$this->db->join('product_type', 'product_type.tCategory = product.type', 'LEFT OUTER');
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Comment: We should not see `$this->uri->segment(2)` in a model method.  Submitted data should be received ONLY in the controller, then distributed to other layers as needed.

Answer (score 0):

try this ,assuming you use id to sort, use `GROUP_BY` instead of `ORDER_BY` and also use `DISTINCT` .. this will work

```
 $this->db->group_by("product.id","ASC");
$this->db->select('product.name, product.price, product.perm_name, product.description, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT product_type.tName SEPARATOR ",") as tName',FALSE); 
$this->db->from('product');
$this->db->where('perm_name', $this->uri->segment(2));
$this->db->join('product_type', 'product_type.tCategory = product.type', 'LEFT OUTER');
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Comment: You should always format your code, this is borderline unreadable

Comment: We should not see `$this->uri->segment(2)` in a model method.  Submitted data should be received ONLY in the controller, then distributed to other layers as needed.