# Join two columns in one columns codeigniter

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

is this possible ? two columns in one columns on table ?

```
$this->db->select('header.*,customer.*,destination.location');
$this->db->from(self::WAYBILL_HEADER_TABLE. " as header");
$this->db->join(self::CUSTOMER_TABLE." as customer","header.consignee = customer.id");
$this->db->join(self::WAYBILLDESTINATION_TABLE. " as destination","header.destination_from = destination.id",'INNER');

$this->db->join(self::WAYBILLDESTINATION_TABLE. " as destinations","header.destination_to = destinations.id",'INNER');
$this->db->where('header.waybilldate <=',$date_to);
$this->db->where('header.waybilldate >=',$date_from);
$this->db->order_by('header.waybillno','DESC');
$query = $this->db->get()->result();
return $query;
```

Comment: Which two columns you are trying to join in one ?

Comment: Are you trying to join two columns in one from the same table.row ?

Comment: yes the WAYBILLDESTINATION_TABLE

Comment: i have 2columns data and i want to join in one column

Comment: Were you thinking of a self join?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1284441/how-does-a-mysql-self-join-work

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $this->db->join('t2', 't1.x = t2.c', 'left');
```

Comment: I think, `OP` wants to join/concat two columns in one from same table.row, not two tables but I could be wrong too.

Comment: Maybe you should provide an explanation to this code snippet. What was wrong with original code? What has changed? Why it should work?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear but to join two columns in one you may use [CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function in your select statement like this

```
$this->db->select('table_name.column1, CONCAT(table_name.column2, ' ', table_name.column3) as table_name.twoInOne');
```

This is just an idea how you can use `concat` function. Also, for group concat check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9322670/codeigniter-group-concat-and-join).

Answer (score 0):

try:

`$this->db->query("SELECT CONCAT(column1,' ',column2) FROM employee_tbl");`

This solution is described at
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-concat-function.htm

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to join two or more columns in same table:

```
    $this->db->select("*");
    $this->db->from("follows");
    $this->db->join('users table1','table1.user_id=follows.following_id','left');
    $this->db->join('users table2','table2.user_id=follows.follower_id','left');
    $this->db->where("table1.is_active",1);
    $this->db->where("table2.is_active",1);
    $res=$this->db->get();
    return $res->result();
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please edit your question and add a bit of explanation/ context, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer for more guidance.